# How to make the GridView adapt to different resolutions in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

In Windows Store apps, if the content is fixed, we can encapsulate it into a ViewBox, so that the content can adapt to different resolutions. But, if the content isn't fixed, in my app, there's a GridView which items are dynamical, how to make it adapt to different resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an adaptive layout, you can use controls like a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) to dynamically grow based on screen resolution.  See more at [Guidelines for scaling to screens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx).  Also, check out the template projects in Visual Studio 2012.  They use adaptive layouts for their content.